# how do Higher Order function understand a variable which is nod fed through function argument?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to understand the mechanism of higher order function in JavaScript.

The example I read from eloquent JavaScript is as below.

```
function greaterThan(n){
  
  return m=>m>n;
}

const greaterThan10=greaterThan(10);

console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

I was wondering how do JS automatically recognizes the variable 'm' which wasn't passed to the function as a second variable in a higher order.
I assumed that any variable defined in a higher order function is reserved for the higher order.
Then I tested it out doing like below.

```
function greaterThan(n){
  console.log(m)
  return m=>m>n;
}
```

It throws an error which means my assumption was wrong.
How do JS prepare itself in a higher order function as it does in the first example.
The code seems like it prepared itself saying

" m is not a parameter passed by its function, however it is going to be passed later on in a higher order."

How did it prepared itself for the higher order function? and why my trial (the second approach) is not working?

Comment: `m` is a parameter of the function `m=>m>n` and therefore can be used only inside this function.

Comment: @marzelin Or, I guess, higher order function should return something and the higher value can only be passed into by 'return'. Maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code annotated below:

```
function greaterThan(n){
  console.log(m); // At this point the below function doesn't exist and has not been called yet
  return m => m > n; // You're returning a function here with a parameter named m;
}
```

When you call `greaterThan(10)` you're getting a `function`, which needs two inputs to return a result:

- `m` which resolves when you further call the function returned by `greaterThan(10)`
- `n` which is is a reference to the `greaterThan` parameter. It is kept alive (not destroyed by the garbage collector) thanks to the JavaScript's [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) mechanism

Answer (score 2):

`m` in this case is the parameter of the lambda function which is returned by `greaterThan`.

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
   // This is lambda function which uses n from the greaterThan function and has m as a parameter
   return (m) => m > n;
}


const greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);

// This equals to this:
const greaterThan10 = (m) => m > 10;

// Which equals to this:
function greaterThan10(m) {
  return m > 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function greaterThan(n){
  
  return m=>m>n;
```

// here u are actually returning a arrow fn which will take m as paramater

```
}


const greaterThan10=greaterThan(10);
```

// the returned fn reference will be assigned to greaterThan10
// greaterThan10 =  m => m>11

```
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

// here u are passing 11 as a paramater to the arrow fn which u are returning

U are trying to log m before u send the parameter m